# HTML optional attribute

Tags: elm

if `containerClassName` is an optional `String`, given this html

```
div
    [ class containerClassName ]
    []
```

how can I make it optional?

For example, if `containerClassName` is `""`, then omit the attribute so the resulting DOM does not include the attribute `class` without a value.

Answer (score 5):

One of the options is to use [classList](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/2.0.0/Html-Attributes#classList) function from `Html.Attributes`, which includes a class if a certain condition is `True`:

```
div
    [ classList
        [ (containerClassName, not (String.isEmpty containerClassName))
        ]
    ]
    []
```

Answer (score 1):

`Elm/core` has the famous `Maybe` type that you can use to model your "optional" behaviour. So your `containerClassName` should be with a `Maybe String` type.

Then you would need a function that wraps the `class` function and accept a `Maybe String`.

```
maybeClass: Maybe String -> List(Html.Attribute msg)
maybeClass maybeClassName =
    case maybeClassName of
        Just className ->
            [class className]
        Nothing ->
            []
```

And you would use this new function like so

```
div
    [] ++ (maybeClass containerClassName)
    []
```

Notice that I chose to return a `List` type and not a single `Attribute` because there is no 'null' type in Elm, but there is an empty list and when you append a list with an empty list it would do what you want.